# Removing a pattern substring from a string PHP

Tags: php, regex

I am creating a systems that could upload a text file and read it then it will determine if the employees are late or on time. Here is the look of the text file when I upload and display it in the system:

"G international School Sta. Rita, Aguna ephone: 049-123-231; Website: http://www.blabla.com; Email: GIS TIMESHEET REPORT From March 01, 2015 to March 05, 2015 Employee: ADET, RES JAY (NT012-003) Date In 1 Out 1 In 2 Out 2 In 3 Out 3 In 4 Out 4 In 5 Out 5 In 6 Out 6 s RequiredHrs Brers Worked Hrs OT Hrs UT 03/02/2015 6:46 am 5:42 pm 10.00 0.00 10.00 0.93 0.00 Employee: APOLO, KERY (FC08-002) Date In 1 Out 1 In 2 Out 2 In 3 Out 3 In 4 Out 4 In 5 Out 5 In 6 Out 6 s RequiredHrs Brers Worked Hrs OT Hrs UT 03/01/2015 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00"

The text file is being generated by a biometrics scanner. What I want to do is to get the name which is triggered by the word "Employee" and the date and time which is triggered by the word "UT". So far what I can do is I can remove the in and out words but I cannot seem to see any pattern to get the desired values. Thank you in advance if you could help me.

This is what I would to accomplish:
ADET, RES JAY, 03/02/2015, 6:46 am, 5:42 pm, APOLO, KERY, 03/01/2015

This is what I have now, i used the method "unset" to delete all the "Out" values.

[image: My result]

Comment: Please show your attempts.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: ok I will sho you wait.

Comment: @hjpotter92 here is a new version

Comment: It is likely that the text file is being generated by some 'standard template' according to some 'documented rules' defined for the 'scanner'. Have you access to the 'scanner output file' documentation? I suspect the given output file will be 'fairly easy' to parse.

Comment: @AvinashRaj here is the expected output

Comment: I don't own the scanner, this was just given to us by our contact and told us that this is what we have to use in our system. @RyanVincent

Comment: No documentation about the output provided by the scanner at all?  i do not envy you ;-/

Comment: Non given to me just this text file. :/ @RyanVincent